# C++: cache-friendliness with functors

Tags: c++, pointers, caching, reference

I am making a short (but expensive in CPU/GPU usage) particle system library in C++, in which both performances and modularity are required. I want the user to be able to make his own functors and pass them to an `update()` function, determining exactly how the particles of a given set will evolve each frame (one functor for the color, for the scale, the position...).

This requires the functors to be passed to the function `update()` (as abstract class arguments) by reference or by pointer, which means everytime I call a functor on one particle, my program (and correct me if I'm wrong, I am not sure my understanding of cache layers is correct) will generate a **cache miss** when loading the datas from the functor, then re-generate a cache miss when I want to iterate over the next Particle of the set.

That sounds like a huge waste of CPU time. How could I work around it? Is my understanding of the problem correct? Is there even a problem at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there even a problem at all?

Hard to tell without measurement. You are correct that indirection such as references and pointers has the potential to hurt performance. Whether or not this is the case in your specific program must be determined by measuring.

A frequently used solution to your problem is accepting the functor as a template parameter like this:

```
template <class Functor>
void update (Functor f){...}
```

This way, the function may even be eligible for inlining.

Comment: This solution should work just fine, thank you :) I'll get used to measure these, but I suppose I have to look it up from the "outside" of the code, when executing, right? There is no magical macro that logs every cache miss?

Comment: @NicolasLutz No, sadly there isn't. Tools like cachegrind and profilers like perf help, but optimizing C++ code is still hard work.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to measure the performance hit with these sorts of things.

Depending on the CPU, this might be expensive or nearly free. I'm sorry I don't know details but I know I've seen different profiles of the same code in my own experience.

I believe that most modern CPUs will cache the pointer and speculate through its indirect branch just as it does with function call returns.

However, the best C++ technique here is to make your function into a template that can accept any kind of parameter that *looks like* a function call.

With this the compiler can inline the functor into your function removing any possible penalty.